# is it possible to fix one time using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying to fix one time and that time is current time + 10 minutes and i wanted to use a condition where when the current time is equal to the set time it will run my logic is it possible?
I have tried using moment but not able to completely solve the problem

here is my tried solution

```
 const currentTime = momentTz().tz("Asia/Kolkata");
      console.log(currentTime.valueOf());
      const notificationTime = momentTz()
        .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
        .add(10, "minutes")
        .valueOf();
      // console.log(currentTime);
      console.log(notificationTime);
     // i want to run in this way 
if(notificationTime === currentTime.valueof())
{
//notiifcation send}
```

Comment: You want to perform something after 10 minutes?

Comment: @Kenny yes i want to perform something after 10 minutes. basically i want to fix the after 10 minute time so i can use if condition

Comment: Then why not use `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @Kenny is it not possible in this way ?

Comment: @Kenny I am not sure setTimeout work well because this will run when the request comes

Comment: I am not quite sure, but as far I know `moment` is time/date library, using which you can do oprations on time and date. But if you want to do something after some time interval you should use `setTimeout`

Comment: @Kenny could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

How will code come to know to run script after some time?

You should use `setTimeout` for this

Like

```
setTimeout(() => {
      // your code which has to be executed after 10 minutes
}, 1000 * 60 * 10)
```

Or if you want check after some intervals you can use `setInterval`

Like following code will check for condition after every minute

```
var myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const currentTime = momentTz().tz("Asia/Kolkata");

    if (notificationTime <= currentTime.valueof()) {
       //notiifcation send
       clearInterval(myInterval)
    }
}, 1000 * 60)
```